# How to provision baremetal sever with 10G bandwidth

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I can place order to provision baremetal server with 10G bandwidth from UI. But I got an error when provision 10G bandwidth baremetal server.

The error: SoftLayer_Exception_NotFound: Unable to find price for uplink port speeds with max speed of 10000. (HTTP 500)

But it works when I change the max speed to 1000.

My golang codes

```
vHardwareTemplate := datatypes.Hardware{
    Hostname:                     sl.String("test"),
    Domain:                       sl.String("example.com"),
    ProcessorCoreAmount: sl.Uint(2),
    MemoryCapacity: sl.Uint(2),
    HourlyBillingFlag:            sl.Bool(true),
    Datacenter:                   &datatypes.Location{Name: sl.String("dal10")},
    OperatingSystemReferenceCode: sl.String("UBUNTU_LATEST"),                   
    NetworkComponents: []datatypes.Network_Component{
        { MaxSpeed: sl.Int( 10000 ), RedundancyEnabledFlag: sl.Bool(true) },            
    },
    PrimaryBackendNetworkComponent: &datatypes.Network_Component{           
        NetworkVlan: &datatypes.Network_Vlan{Id: sl.Int(2288425)},          
    },      
}
sess := session.New(userName, apiKey, endpoint)
hardwareService := services.GetHardwareService(sess)
order, err := hardwareService.GenerateOrderTemplate(&vHardwareTemplate)
if err != nil{
    fmt.Printf("%v \n", err)
}else{
    jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.MarshalIndent(order, "", "    ")
   if jsonErr != nil {
          fmt.Println(jsonErr)
          return
   }
   fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the [Hardware_Server::GenerateOrderTemplate](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/generateOrderTemplate/) method you only can use in the configuration for the new server the values displayed for the [Hardware_Server::getCreateObjectOptions](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/generateOrderTemplate/) and this method is not displaying any option for a server with 10GB bandwidth.

You need to keep in mind that the methods that you are using are limited, because these methods have been designed for fast provision and not to emulate the same behavior as the UI, that's why you cannot set the same options as the UI does.

If you want to have the same options as the UI you need to use the [Product_Order::placeOrder](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder/) method, the drawback of this method is that use it is not too easy as the generateOrderTemplate method.

```
/*
Get package location.

This script will retrieve a collection of valid locations for a given package
by calling to SoftLayer_Product_Package::getLocations method.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getLocations

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
*/
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    // SoftLayer API username and key
    username := "set me"
    apikey   := "set me"

    // The id of package you wish to get its item prices
    packageId := 46             // Virtual Server Instance

    // Create SoftLayer API session
    sess := session.New(username, apikey)

    // Get SoftLayer_Product_Package service
    service := services.GetProductPackageService(sess)

    // Call the getItemPrices() method.
    locations, err := service.Id(packageId).GetLocations()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\n Unable to retrieve Item Prices from Package:\n - %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Following helps to print the result in json format.
    for _,location := range locations {
        jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.Marshal(location)
        if jsonErr != nil {
            fmt.Println(jsonErr)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we have any sample code to do that? My requirement is place an order to provision baremetal server with 10G bandwidth. The CPU, Memory and Disk are not cared.

Comment: The Product_Order function is really not easy to use. Like I have no idea about the packageID, prices item etc.

Comment: https://softlayer.github.io/python/orderBareMetal/ see that example the page contains more example that may help you

Comment: Also see documentation to undertand  better the placeOrder method https://softlayer.github.io/blog/bpotter/Going-Further-SoftLayer-API-Python-Client-Part-3/

Comment: Finally I found all parameters and all the api to to placeOrder. And I checked the order was approved(auto approve) from SL portal.  So how do I know when the baremetal server will be provisioned from API? My code needs go to next steps when the server is ready.  BTW I provisioned server with package ID 911(the Single E3-1270 v6).

Comment: Another question is do we have API to shutdown the public interface? From SL portal we can select "disconnect" attribute from speed field.

Comment: The location attribute in Container_Product_Order is different with datatypes.Location. For example I use "dal10" in datatypes.Location, but I need to use "DALLAS10" for Container_Product_Order.Location. How can I get the location name list for  Container_Product_Order.Location?

Comment: I suggest you to split your question and submit them as new entries in the forum, this metod should return you the valid locations for a package https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getRegions/ you can use the ID or the name

Comment: I tried the getRegions API got error  - SoftLayer_Exception: Object does not exist to execute method on. (SoftLayer_Product_Package::getRegions) (HTTP 500) 
 service2 := services.GetProductPackageService(sess)
 service2.Id(911)
 data,err := service2.GetRegions()
 if err != nil{
  fmt.Printf("\n Get date error:\n - %s\n", err)
  return
 }

Comment: see the example in my answer and I recomend you read all the documentation that you can first, there are many questions answered there